# ISR library in colab not working, AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Tags: python, isr

```
from ISR.models import RDN, RRDN

model = RDN(weights='noise-cancel')
```

Then it gives me this error. What can I do?

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> 5
> 6 #model = RDN(weights='noise-cancel')
> ----> 7 model = RRDN(weights='gans') # default
> 8 #model = RDN(weights='psnr-small')
> 9 # model = RDN(weights='psnr-large')
>
> 3 frames
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py
> in load_weights_from_hdf5_group(f, layers)
> 649   """
> 650   if 'keras_version' in f.attrs:
> --> 651     original_keras_version = f.attrs['keras_version'].decode('utf8')
> 652   else:
> 653     original_keras_version = '1'
>
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: Are you using an old version of that library? `str.decode()` exists on Python 2, where strings are byte arrays and might represent text in a non-ASCII encoding that needs to be in encoding. In Python 3 that's on the `bytes` type. Current version says it supports Python 3 so maybe you just need an upgrade?

Comment: I'm using Colab which has python 3.7.12 (default, Sep 10 2021, 00:21:48). The ISR library is compatible with Python 3.6, https://pypi.org/project/ISR/ . So it should work on Colab, no?

Comment: Add `import sys; print(sys.version)` to your script and see what version is actually being used to run your script.

Comment: I did, and it says: 3.7.12 (default, Sep 10 2021, 00:21:48) 
[GCC 7.5.0]

Answer (score 0):

- I have the same problem and I found solution on [github](https://github.com/idealo/image-super-resolution/issues/197)
- install `h5py==2.10.0` to be compatible with `ISR` library

```py
!pip install 'h5py==2.10.0' --force-reinstall
!pip install ISR
```